# Looping a formula through numerous spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following three Excel (2010) formulas which perform exactly what I want them to:

```
=IF([NoData]Sheet1!C4=ISBLANK(TRUE)," ",[NoData]Sheet1!A4)
=IF([NoData]Sheet1!C4=ISBLANK(TRUE)," ",[NoData]Sheet1!C4)
=IF([NoData]Sheet1!C4=ISBLANK(TRUE)," ",[NoData]Sheet1!K4)
```

I want these three formulas to run through data in several worksheets contained within a given workbook. The cells that they will operate on will remain the same for each worksheet.

How can I run these three formulas through 11 or 12 different worksheets within the given workbook?

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit? You just want to know how to use the same formulas for other sheets too? Or to *put* them on other sheets?  This sentence is a little convoluted, "How can I run these three formulas through 11 or 12 different worksheets within the given workbook to return me a table containing the information that it will return me?"

Comment: Have a look at the posts on here for things like this, i think the one above yours is asking the same thing

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne I would like to be able to automatically run these three forumlas through the other sheets in the workbook as well. Hope this makes it slightly clearer.

Comment: Do they really perform as you want to? ISBLANK(TRUE) always returns false, so you are checking if the value in sheet 1, cell C4 is equal to false, not if cell C4 is blank..

Comment: And no it doesn't make it any clearer, you should probably explain what you are trying to achieve as your formulae don't make sense either. If you are checking this on multiple sheets, are you only not returning a value if all cells on all sheets are blank? If that's the case, what are you returning when multiple cells are not blank, or are you trying to repeat the same set of formulae (which are still wrong) for each sheet in the workbook?

Comment: Hi @NickDewitt - the formulae as they are achieve what i want them to. The only thing I want to know is how to loop these formulae through different worksheets automatically so that I save myself the time-consuming task of typing out the formulae again and again manually.

Comment: But my point is, you don't understand what the formula is doing. What you have is equivalent to `=IF([NoData]Sheet1!C4=FALSE," ",[NoData]Sheet1!A4)`.

Comment: I do understand what the formula is doing, the '[NoData]' parts are substitutes for the real name of the workbook which I would rather not disclose on here. The only thing I am asking is if there is a way of looping these formulae so that they execute on data in all of the worksheets in the '[NoData]' workbook. I have already manually executed all three formulae for one of the worksheets in this workbook, and it has worked perfectly. I just want to save myself the time of having to type the formulae out again and again for each worksheet.

Comment: You need VBA to do this.  From reading your comments, you are looking for a macro that puts this formula on all sheets.  There's not a way I know of to do this without a macro. (And using @NickDewitt's formula, you could return all the info on the same sheet. But that doesn't seem like what you want).

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, thanks for your comment. Do you know what sort of VBA script I would have to execute in order to achieve my aim? Thanks

Comment: Where do you want those three formulas on each sheet? And the `Sheet1` part should change to reflect the sheet it's on, correct?

Comment: I would like the formulas to operate between cells C4 and K200 on every worksheet. And yes 'Sheet1' would change every time the worksheet changes. Thanks

Comment: I would have suggested using vba, but the refusal to even try to understand how a formula evaluates leads me to believe that it is pointless and this is more of a 'can you do my homework for me, but I don't want to understand the answer' type question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use VBA to achieve this, but given the state of your original formulae I wouldn't suggest taking that route.

Use the indirect function to vary the name of the sheet that your are putting into your formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[NoData]Sheet",A1,"!A1")))," ",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[NoData]Sheet",A1,"!K4")))
```

In cell A1 on the sheet for the formula above, put the sheet number that you want the formula to target.

I will reiterate though, `ISBLANK(TRUE)` always resolves to FALSE, so in your formula you are checking if the value in C4 is FALSE, not if it is blank.

Comment: The formulae return a blank cell if the cell in question is blank (true), but return another cell containing information that I require if the cell in question is not blank (false). It does the job which is all that matters.

Comment: No it doesn't, it returns a space `" "` if the cell in question equals `FALSE`, luckily for you a blank cell returns 0 which is also equal to `FALSE`, but you are completely misunderstanding the use of `ISBLANK` and how formulae work in general.

Comment: The =IF statement in Excel requires a logical test, followed by an output IF TRUE (which in my case I have specified to be a blank cell), finally followed by an output if the logical test proves to be FALSE (which I have specified in this case to return a cell with information in it). Like I said, these formulae are returning exactly what I want them to, I just want to be able to automatically loop them to repeat from several worksheets. You have done nothing to provide any assistance in achieving this so please stop commenting on this query. Thank you.

Comment: You are wrong, try the formula with `=FALSE` instead of `=ISBLANK(TRUE)`, you get the same result. `ISBLANK(TRUE)` always resolves to false. You should be putting the cell value into the ISBLANK formula to check if a cell is blank, you do not understand how the logical test part of the formula works.

Comment: If you don't believe me, use the `evaluate formula` option on the formulas tab of the ribbon and watch it resolve.

Comment: You are being very pedantic. If I'm honest I don't really care as long as I am given the outputs that I require (which I am). As I said please stop commenting on this question now. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should read the rules of these forums, ill flag your 'question' for deletion.

Comment: ...Or you could just stop commenting on this question. I would still like to keep this question open to others to comment on. I would just like YOU personally to stop commenting now.

Comment: Nobody wants to because it's a stupid question from someone who doesn't understand how formulas work in general let alone excel and doesn't want to listen to any answers

Comment: No one likes a keyboard warrior Nick. Get a life and get off this question. I would listen to an answer if it came from a competent person.

Comment: I have already spent my time to give you an answer and explained what was wrong with your current formula, the fact that you are too ignorant to understand it is your problem.